# Bootstrap 4 How to Overlap Two Divs that Stack Responsively

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm a backend guy and trying to figure out a few details for a project we have that's using Bootstrap 4.

Simply put, we want to create the layout that's executed here: 
https://codepen.io/mediumandmessage/pen/xVeXop

(this example and the code below is from the original Bootstrap 3 example I found, not Bootstrap 4)

HTML:

```css
.somesection {margin-top:50px!important;}
body {
  font-size:17px;
  font-family:Helvetica Neue;
}
img {max-width:100%;}

.overlay-text {
  font-size:3.5vw;
  float:right;
  width:65%; /*important*/
  bottom:21vw; /*important*/
  padding: 25px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container somesection">
  <div class="row col-xs-6">  
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459664018906-085c36f472af?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1087&h=725&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-4 overlay-text">
      This is some text that should partially overlay.
  </div>
</div>
```

However, that example uses Bootstrap 3 and breaks in Bootstrap 4 (the text displays horizontally below the image) and also does not stack the divs responsively.

I've tried screwing around with `absolute` and `relative` positioning, etc. it became a lot of code to execute cleanly and make responsive and I was hoping someone out there may have some insight into implementing in pure Bootstrap4...

If anyone out there can share any expertise here, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a transform to your overlay column (you may need to cancel this with a media query for your smaller screens).

Please note in the html below, I have fixed your code to work with boostrap 4 - columns have to be inside a row (they cannot be on a row) and I don't think there is a `-xs` class any more

```css
.overlay-text {
  /* these two are needed - the align self makes the column not stretch the whole height of the image column and the translate moves the column over the image */
  align-self: flex-start;
  transform: translateX(-20%);

  /* the following are for example only */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container somesection">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459664018906-085c36f472af?format=auto&amp;auto=compress&amp;dpr=1&amp;crop=entropy&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1087&amp;h=725&amp;q=80" class="w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4 overlay-text">
      This is some text that should partially overlay.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/PhXFSteOLZ)

Comment: Thanks! Worked just how I needed. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:relative;` to the `.overlay-text`
You can also adjust the value of `bottom`

```css
.somesection {margin-top:50px!important;}
body {
  font-size:17px;
  font-family:Helvetica Neue;
}
img {max-width:100%;}

.overlay-text {
  font-size:3.5vw;
  float:right;
  width:65%; /*important*/
  bottom:21vw; /*important*/
  padding: 25px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container somesection">
  <div class="row col-xs-6">  
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459664018906-085c36f472af?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1087&h=725&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-4 overlay-text">
      This is some text that should partially overlay.
  </div>
</div>
```